# Google Compute Engine (GCE) Windows - Reset Password

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, google-compute-engine

Is there any way to reset the password on a GCE Windows instance (Server 2008 R2). I have an old password in a snapshot that I'm creating an instance from and I can't RDP into it.

I can create a disk from the snapshot and attach that to another instance but can't see a way to reset the password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from Google gave me a workaround in a Google Group. Just needed to run:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata <INSTANCE> --zone <ZONE> --metadata windows-startup-script-cmd="net user <USERNAME> <PASSWORD>"
```

and then reboot!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your username and password from the metadata server, using the gcloud compute instances describe command, visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#starting_a_new_windows_virtual_machine_instance) for more information. If the password is expired, the RDP client will ask you to change the password.

Comment: That just gets me password generated when the instance was created from the snapshot. This doesn't work. It's possible that I previously had to change the password within Windows before I took the snapshot... would this cause the default password reset mechanisms of GCE not to work?